# How to get multiple tuple output from Function in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
create function sk( age int) returns  varchar(30) deterministic
     begin
     declare value varchar(30);
     select sname into value from student where student.age=age;
     return value;
     end;
     //

select sk(19);
```

> ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row

Answer (score 0):

You neet to set `LIMIT 1` in your `SELECT` statement, with this you will have a scalar instead of a dataset.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION sk(age INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(30) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE value VARCHAR(30);
    SELECT sname INTO value 
    FROM student 
    WHERE student.age = age
    LIMIT 1;
    RETURN value;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```